# Determining whether a number contains a given power of two in its sum

Tags: algorithm, performance, math

Very badly worded title, but I couldn't think of how to summarise the problem.

Essentially, every number can be formed by adding powers of two where each number appears at most once. e.g. 20=16+4, 27=16+8+2+1, etc.

What's the most efficient way of determining whether a given number occurs in this decomposition of another number?

It wouldn't be too hard to simply calculate the full set of numbers to be added, and see if the number appears in that. But there must be some kind of shortcut, right? Calculating the whole set seems overkill when I just need to verify the presence of a given number.

Comment: What do you mean by "number" exactly? That may sound like an odd question, but usually numbers on a computer are already stored as the sum of a bunch of powers of two (that's what binary is).

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the `AND` operator. For example, in Python, `27 & 4` is equal to zero, but `27 & 8` is equal to 8. Also, `bin(27)` shows you all the ones and zeros corresponding to each bit of the number 27.

Comment: This is only really a problem on computers that don't store integers in binary. But if we generalise for base `n`, then yes, your basic option is to start dividing the number with `n` until you reach the n-ary digit you need.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking how to check whether a particular bit is set.

The question "does the number 2**x appear in the decomposition of y?" is equivalent to the question "is bit x set in the binary representation of y?".

So you can use bitwise operators to check - pseudo-code:

```
bit_is_set = (y & 2**x != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Get the binary representation of the number.
- See if the bit that represents the power of 2 you are looking for, is set or not.

---

Example:

To find whether 256 (= 100000000<sub>2</sub>) is made up of 4 ( = 100<sub>2</sub>), see that the 3<sup>rd</sup> bit of binary representation of 256 is set or not. In this case it is not set.

Also, see that 260 (= 10000100<sub>2</sub>) is indeed made of 4 because its 3rd bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

List of powers of 2 that form the number:

`[2 ** (31 - i) for i, j in enumerate('{0:032b}'.format(x)) if j == '1']`

and then you can do a membership test with `in`.

```
>>> x
27
>>> [2 ** (31 - i) for i, j in enumerate('{0:032b}'.format(x)) if j == '1']
[16, 8, 2, 1]
>>> 4 in [2 ** (31 - i) for i, j in enumerate('{0:032b}'.format(x)) if j == '1']
False
```

Where

- `'{0:032b}'.format(x)` formats the number as a 32-bit binary string.
- `enumerate('{0:032b}'.format(x))` is used to assign an index to each bit.
- We then look for bits that are 1 (`j == '1'`), and extract the corresponding power of 2 `2 ** (31 - i)`.